# Measuring and maintaining the diversity of individuals in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-computing

While I was using the Genetic Algorithm to generate full correct Sudoku grids starting from a population of random grids, I occasionally face the problem of the process being stuck on a local maxima until the population loses its diversity.

So, I decided to find a mechanism for maintaining the diversity of the population to avoid the problem. What I thought about was:

- Measuring the diversity of each individual by computing how different it is from the rest of the population:

  For each individual $i$ : $$diversity_i = \sum_j distance(i, j)$$ and I used the hamming distance as the $distance$ function.
- Ranking the individuals (for selection) based on both their diversity and their fitness.

I faced two problem with this approach:

1. Computing the diversity this way is expensive as it requires $n^2$ call to the $distance$ function (which is itself not a constant time function), raising the following question: what is a relatively optimal way for measuring the diversity of a population?
2. How to rank the individuals of a population based on both diversity and fitness?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to rank the individuals of a population based on both diversity and fitness?

You can combine diversity and fitness into a single score: $$score(i) = fitness(i) + k \cdot diversity(i)$$

It's a standard approach and doesn't require significant changes to the algorithm. Unfortunately $k$ is **problem-specific**.

---

Alternatively change the standard GA to a multi-objective evolutionary  algorithm (MOEA).

This needs a lot of changes (e.g. the algorithm now needs to maintain a set of Pareto optimal individuals).

MOEA is probably a overkill for what you're doing. Indeed it's very interesting and a good training.

---

> Computing the diversity this way is expensive... What is a relatively optimal way for measuring the diversity of a population?

The genotypic / structural approach to diversity isn't the only workable one.

Instead of measuring how differently the individuals look like, measure how  differently those individuals behave (***phenotypic diversity***).

A great advantage is the ease of computation: often an acceptable approximation is the simple fitness value.

Schemes like Fitness Uniform Selection / [Fitness Uniform Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0610126) generate selection pressure toward sparsely populated fitness regions, not necessarily toward higher fitness:

[image: FUSS]
*Evolution of the population under FUSS versus standard selection schemes (STD): STD may get stuck in a local optimum if all unfit individuals were eliminated too quickly. In FUSS, all fitness levels remain occupied
with “free” drift within and in-between fitness levels, from which new mutants are steadily created, occasionally leading to further evolution in a more promising direction (from **"Fitness Uniform Optimization" - Marcus Hutter & Shane Legg**).*

Comment: This visualization is great.

Answer (score 4):

What you suggest is OK, but should be done with caution.  After all, there is no functional difference between keeping the population from converging on a local peak and keeping the population from converging on the global peak.

One approach is to use this variant of **@manlio**'s formula $$\mathrm{score}(i) = \mathrm{fitness}(i) + k(g)\, \mathrm{diversity}(i)\,,$$ where now instead of a scaling constant $k$ we apply a scaling function $(g)$ that decreases with increasing generation number $g$.  The idea is that initially $k(g)$ is high, keeping diversity up, but drops with time as the population becomes more and more likely to have generated a point in the vicinity of the global peak, allowing convergence to that peak.

Of course, like all suggestions, this one comes with no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought, not tried, and not backed up by literature. But at least it's more computationally efficient than your current approach. If anyone has thoughts or references, please leave a comment.

I'll assume that your chromosomes consist of binary genes, but an extension to real-valued genes might be possible.

For each gene *g* you could compute the expected value *E*(*g*) of that gene, which is just the average across all individuals. If *g* is 0 in 20% of the population and 1 in the other 80%, then *E*(*g*) would be 0.8. This is an *O*(#individuals × #genes) computation.

The diversity of an individual *i* can then be calculated as the inverse of the probability *P*(*i*) of encountering that individual. For each gene *g* in the individual, compute *P*(*g*); e.g. if *g* is 0 in this individual and *E*(*g*) is 0.8, then *P*(*g*) is 0.2. The final *P*(*i*) is simply the product of *P*(*g*) over all genes. Since this is lower for more "diverse" individuals, we take the reciprocal 1 / *P*(*g*) as a measure for diversity. This is again an *O*(#individuals × #genes) computation.